# Need to write the single logfile by different SP running in different session concurerntly in PL SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c

I want to write the single log file (which gets created on daily basis) by multiple SPs running in different session.

This is what i have done.

```
create or replace PKG_LOG:
procedure SP_LOGFILE_OPEN
      step 1) Open the logfile:
      LF_LOG      := UTL_FILE.FOPEN(LV_FILE_LOC,O_LOGFILE,'A',32760);
end SP_LOGFILE_OPEN;

procedure SP_LOGFILE_write
      step 1) Write the logs as per application need:
      UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(LF_LOG,'whatever i want to write');
      step 2) Flush the content as i want to logs to be written in real time.
      UTL_FILE.FFLUSH(LF_LOG);
end SP_LOGFILE_write;
```

Now whenever in any stored procedure i want to write the log first i am calling SP_LOGFILE_OPEN and then SP_LOGFILE_write(as many time as i want).

Problem is, if there are two stored procedures say SP1 and SP2. If both of them try to open it same concurrently it never throughs error or waits for another to finish. Instead it gets open in both the sessions where SP1 and SP2 is executing.
The content of SP1(if it started running first) will be completly written into logfile but content from SP2 will be partially written into logfile. SP2 starts wrtting only when SP1's execution stops. Also initial content of SP2 which it was trying to write into logfile gets lost due to FFLUSH.
As per my requirement i dont want to lose the content of second SP2 when SP1 was running.
Any suggestions please. I dont want to drop teh idea of FFLUSH as i need in real time.
Thanks.

Comment: What operating system is the Oracle server running on?

Comment: Why don't you log to a table?

Comment: @BobJarvis: Its running on solaris SunOS 5.11 11.3

Comment: @Gary_W: We have some restriction on using table space

Comment: Flushing in real time after every write? That's not going to be very good performance-wise. I suggest you write N rows to a table, then have a separate job that dumps the contents of the table to the file and then removes the rows from the log table.

Comment: Thanks Steven. We are thinking to change the approch. But just out of curiosity, is it even possible to write one file from 2 session (running different Stored procedures in each) without impacting the contents of file. like if SP1 gets hold of file, SP2 should not update it until it gets hold of file.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `DBMS_LOCK` to get a custom lock or wait until a lock is available, then do your write, then release the lock. It has to be serialized.

But this will make your concurrency problem even *worse*. You're basically saying that all calls to this procedure must get in a line and be processed one by one. And remember that disk I/O is slow, so your database is now only as fast as your disk.

Answer (score 0):

Yours is a bad idea. Instead of writing directly to a file, simply enqueue a log message to an Oracle advanced queue and create a job running very frequently (every few seconds) to dequeue from the AQ. It's the procedure invoked by the job that actually writes to the file. This way you can synchronize different SP executions trying to log concurrently on the same file. The actual logging is made by one single SP invoked by the job.